# Spring Boot & reactor-netty https multiple domains

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, netty, project-reactor

I'm trying to configure a spring cloud gateway, (on top of project Reactor) to serve HTTPS across two domains.

However it appears that it is unable to use SNI to choose the correct certificate to show to the client.

My configuration is as follows:

- I've generated two different private key/ certs and both of those are stored in `keystore.jks`. Both of them have different CommonNames and they also have Subject Alternative Names that match the expected domains.
- I've entered the common name into my hosts files to fool browser/curl into thinking that its two separate domains.

The relevant parts of `application.yml` are:

```
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    # The entire purpose of this project is so that client authentication is needed
    client-auth: need

---

spring:
  profiles: development

server:
  ssl:
    key-store: config/keystore.jks
    trust-store: config/truststore.jks
```

The purpose of this is to enable 2 way ssl authentication with two different clients both of whom issue us with their own certificates.

I know netty which is the foundation for spring cloud gateway supports SNI. Is there any way to configure SNI for spring cloud gateway?

Comment: This is a function of spring boot itself, nothing specific to gateway

Comment: @spencergibb Thank you are you suggesting I remove gateway from the questions?

Comment: @spencergibb Also I think if your associated with the project it may be good to show that on your profile.

Comment: No, just that the functionality is not provided by gateway itself, but by spring boot

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an outstanding issue for [Spring Boot to Support SNI](https://spring-projects/spring-boot#26022)

An earlier [ticket for Spring Cloud](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1525) was closed by the issue creator who appeared to answer their own question. This issue links to another [issue in reactor-netty](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/573) for an SNI implemetation, which has now been done.

Comment: This feature request will be available with 1.0.0-RC1